# Redirecting standard iostream of JSch to primefaces' terminal

Tags: java, primefaces, inputstream, outputstream, jsch

I'm using Primefaces' Terminal component and JSch to ssh to a remote desktop. With the exec channel the execution takes too much time as both session and channel closes at each command and I didn't manage to avaid that. So I changed the channel to shell and now I'm trying to "redirect" standard input/outputsteam. Here's what my code looks like :

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TerminalController implements Serializable{  

     public TerminalController(){
     jsch=new JSch();
     InputStream in=null;
     PrintStream out=System.out;
try{
                      session=jsch.getSession(user, ip, port);
                      session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                        session.setPassword(passwd);
                        session.connect();
                       channel=session.openChannel("shell");    
                       channel.setInputStream(in);
                       channel.setOutputStream(out);
                       channel.connect();
}catch(Exception ee){
                      System.out.println(ee);
} }
    public String handleCommand(String command, String[] params) {  
     command=command+StringUtils.join(params," ");

                   in=IOUtils.toInputStream(command);
                  String result=out.toString();
                   out.flush();
                    return result;}
```

I know it's a mess, I'm still a beginner in java. 
Another problem I thought about is that in the conversion from iostream to string I may lose the enter button function ! I'm waiting for you suggestions, solutions and pieces of advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `in` variable has no effect on the channel, and calling `out.toString()` will not get you any results.

You need to **write** the command (with its parameters) to the channel, and then read the output from there. Also, don't use the `setInputStream` or `setOutputStream` methods (they are good if you have existing streams from which to read or to which to write, which you don't).

```
public class TerminalController implements Serializable{  

    BufferedReader fromChannel;
    PrintWriter toChannel;
    Channel channel;
    Session session;

     public TerminalController(){
        jsch=new JSch();
        try {
            session=jsch.getSession(user, ip, port);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setPassword(passwd);
            session.connect();
            channel = session.openChannel("shell");    
            InputStream inStream = channel.getInputStream();
            fromChannel = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream, "UTF-8"));
            OutputStream outStream = channel.getOutputStream();
            toChannel = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outStream, "UTF-8"));
            channel.connect();
        } catch(Exception ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String handleCommand(String command, String[] params) {  
         command = command + StringUtils.join(params," ");
         toChannel.println(command);
         StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
         while(true) {
            String line = fromChannel.readLine();
            result.append(line);
            if(looksLikePrompt(line))
               return result.toString();
            result.append("\n");
         }
    }
}
```

The hard part is actually knowing when the output from the remote command is finished, and you need to return (this is in the `looksLikePrompt` method I don't know how to write).

I'm not sure that the `CommandHandler` principle of Primeface's terminal component is the right design for creating an interactive terminal, where the terminal shouldn't need to know when a command is finished. What happens when a command needs more input?

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Well the fact that Primefaces' terminal component is not a wise choice for a terminal emulation is something I figured out too late. To be honest the two things that I liked about it are : personalizable prompt (with xhtml attribute) and command history (up to 100 or more). looksLikePrompt method I can work it out but I got bigger problems. At first I started using Exec channel but I can't reuse the same channel and even session more than once I tried conditional structure and it didn't work.I'm not completely understanding JSch.

Comment: Each exec channel can only be used once (for one command), but you should be able to use the same session. Don't use session.disconnect() between the individual commands (after that, you'll need a new session).

Comment: I didn't use session.disconnect() ! I think what my code is missing is Thread.sleep(n); Or the choice of the bean scope ends the session automatically after each command.

Comment: @infonize thanks for the edit proposal, I've fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole;
import org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiString;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TerminalController {
    BufferedReader fromChannel;
    PrintWriter toChannel;
    Channel channel;
    Session session;
    JSch jsch;

    public TerminalController() {
        jsch = new JSch();
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession("leoks", "localhost", 22);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setPassword("xxx");
            session.connect(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // 3 secs timeout
            channel = session.openChannel("shell");
            InputStream inStream = channel.getInputStream();
            fromChannel = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream,
                    "UTF-8"));
            OutputStream outStream = channel.getOutputStream();
            toChannel = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outStream,
                    "UTF-8"));
            channel.connect();

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            boolean stop = false;
            while (!stop) {
                // prompt does not end with newline...
                char c = (char) fromChannel.read();
                result.append(c);
                System.out.print(c);
                if (result.toString().endsWith("$")) {
                    System.out.print("<<<");
                    stop = true;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String handleCommand(String command, String[] params)
            throws IOException {
        command = command + " " + StringUtils.join(params, " ");
        toChannel.println(command);
        toChannel.flush();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        AnsiConsole.systemInstall();
        while (true) {
            char c = (char) fromChannel.read();
            result.append(c);
            if (c == '$') {
                AnsiString as = new AnsiString(result.toString());
                String s = as.getPlain().toString();
                s = s.replaceAll("\n", "<br>");
                AnsiConsole.systemUninstall();
                return s;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Jansi also have an HTML rendering class that needs some work to properly replace \n with BR since terminal component renders HTML and silently ignores any malformed string full of control codes. You may also want to replace terminal CSS definition with a fixed-width font, for example, using a CSS such as

```
.ui-widget
{
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

and

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Terminal POC</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css" />
    <h:form>
        <p:terminal 
            commandHandler="#{terminalController.handleCommand}"
            height="300px" 
            welcomeMessage="Welcome..." 
            prompt="&gt;" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```